# Can we do git reset after git push

Tags: git, github

On https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/undoing-changes#!reset we see the following line about `git reset`:

`it should only be used to undo local changes—you should never reset snapshots that have been shared with other developers.`

Does it advice not to do a `git reset` after a `git push`?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @hobbs I made a few commits and pushed them to origin. Now I realized that I want to undo some commits. Rather than doing several `git revert`, will a `git reset` work at this point?

Answer (score 1):

An example of what you don’t want to do is

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Super swell commit'
$ git push origin master
$ git reset --hard master~3
$ git push -f origin master
```

On a busy repository, pulling the rug from beneath other developers’ feet will [force additional work onto them](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase).

If the number of collaborators is very small, you may be able to get away with the quick cleanup you want to do.